# Regex rule match up to string

Tags: sed, grep, pcre

I need to used grep / egrep / sed to extract certain parts out of a SNORT rule string.

given a string that can be in the format:

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"Some message"; 
content:"c1"; content:"GET /blah"; offset:0; depth:9; content:"something else";)
```

How would I go about extracting just the following:

```
content:"GET /blah"; offset:0; depth:9;
```

Given that the following are true:

- It must match up until the start of the next content match (if there is one)
- A rule may only have this content term, it may have more and they may be in any order
- Other modifiers may be applied before, after or in between the offset and depth operators, they must also be extracted as follows:

`content:"GET "; offset:5; http_uri; depth:12;`

Rules can be "malformed" i.e. instead of having a single semicolon after the content term it may have two or more.

What I have so far which I believe would work in other regex systems is:

```
(GET|POST).*?(?=content)
```

The idea behind this being that `.*?` is an ungreedy match on any character any number of times and a non grabbing (not sure if that's the term) match on the next term "content".

I believe this breaks though if there is no following content term and also doesn't seem to extract anything in grep or egrep.

Not sure what to do, any ideas?

Comment: I got a similar question recently, maybe it will be helpful: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969677/how-to-run-grep-command-for-a-range-of-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
grep -Po '\bcontent\s*:\s*"(GET|POST)\b[^"]*"((?!;\s*content\s*:)[^"]|"[^"]*")*;'
```

Sample input:

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"Some message"; 
content:"c1"; content:"GET /blah"; offset:0; depth:9; content:"something else";)
content:"GET "; offset:5; http_uri; depth:12;
```

Output:

```
content:"GET /blah"; offset:0; depth:9;
content:"GET "; offset:5; http_uri; depth:12;
```

Explanation:

- Instead of looking ahead for the next `content`, I am using a *negative* lookahead to consume anything other than the word `content`. This way, end of line also qualifies as the end of the match.

The regex in detail:

- `\b` - word boundary (to prevent matching e.g. `othercontent`)
- `content\s*:\s*` - literally: content followed by a colon; with optional spaces
- `"` - opening quote
- `(GET|POST)` - either one of these verbs
- `\b` - word boundary (to prevent matching e.g. `POSTAL`)
- `[^"]*"` - everything upto and including the closing quote
- `(` - begin repeating subpattern
- `(?!;\s*content\s*:)` - negative lookahead, to make sure we stop before any subsequent `content`
- `[^"]` - any non-quote; spaces, letters, colons, semicolons...
- `|` - or...
- `"[^"]*"` - some attribute string; matching this as a whole to prevent the negative lookahead to pick up something between quotes
- `)*` - end repeating subpattern; zero or more times
- `;` - closing semicolon

Comment: Nearly although I don't want to keep any content terms that don't have GET in them or in fact more specifically GET or POST.  But I can always run that as a second grep after the one you've written to only keep those with GET|POST in.

Comment: Sorry about that; I will refine it a bit.